# How to delete default session (Xfce4) from Debian?

Tags: debian, session

I want to delete default session (Xfce4) from Debian.

I don't want to damage Debian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just the session:

```bsh
sudo apt remove xfce4-session
```

or everything related to XFCE:

```bsh
sudo apt autoremove 'xfce4*'
```

Comment: `purge` may be better than `remove` in this instance so config files be removed as well. Users may also want to check their `~/.dmrc` in case it referenced that session.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`tasksel`](https://wiki.debian.org/tasksel) by removing [task-xfce-desktop](https://packages.debian.org/buster/task-xfce-desktop):

```
sudo tasksel remove task-xfce-desktop
```